# The inverse of a transpose matrix to "cancel" the transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-equations

When it comes to solving and equation containing matrices I don't always understand some of the rules involved. In particular, I am trying to figure out the derivation of the Gauss-Newton algorithm. In this particular case I have to solve for $z$:

$A^TAz = A^Tb$

According to wikipedia, the solution to this is:

$z = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$

I understand what they are doing here, but why can't you do the following?:

$(A^T)^{-1}A^TAz = (A^T)^{-1}A^Tb$

$Az = b$

$z = A^{-1}b$

I have had this question for some time while reading various derivations. What is the underlying rule that prevents me from doing it the second way?

Comment: You can't do that when $A$ is not a square matrix. On the other hand, $A^TA$ is always square.

Comment: Assuming $A$ is a square matrix and invertible, then $A^TA$ is invertible.

What you did was exactly the same as what they did.Note that they ended up with $z = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$. But $(A^TA)^{-1}=A^{-1}\left(A^T\right)^{-1}$, so $$z = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb=A^{-1}\left(A^T\right)^{-1}A^Tb=A^{-1}Ib=A^{-1}b.$$

Comment: If $A$ isn't a square matrix and it is full rank, whether $A^TA$ is invertible or not depends on whether the $A$ more rows than columns or the other way around.

Comment: Ah. So the kicker is that only square matrices are invertible. In my case, $A$ is not necessarily square. If I knew that $A$ was square, I would be able to get away with that.